# Coldfusion - modifying the output prior to SerializeJSon?

Tags: json, coldfusion

Firstly, apologies for the phrasing in the question - I couldn't come up with anything better, sorry!

Here's the scenario - I'm working with a JS Front-end that I have little control over, and a Coldfusion backend that I do control.

Everything is working fine, with one slight exception - which I'm hoping will be an easy fix!  The database currently stores only the filename of an image, however the front-end requires the full url.  Therefore, I somehow need to append the domain (which will always be the same) prior to SerializeJson. I've tried a few things without success so far, and haven't been able to find any syntax examples.

My existing code is below;

```
<cfquery name="qryNames">
    SELECT ID, imgthumb, imgfull 
    FROM   images 
    ORDER BY ID DESC
</cfquery>

<cfset data = [] />

<cfoutput query="qryNames">
    <cfset obj = {
                   "thumb" = ImgThumb,
                   "image" = Imgfull
                 } />
    <cfset arrayAppend(data, obj) />
</cfoutput>

<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">
<cfoutput>
    #serializeJSON(data)#
</cfoutput>
</cfprocessingdirective>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No" showdebugoutput="No">
```

For clarity, this is what I'm looking for...

```
<cfset obj = {
                "thumb" = http://mydomain/ImgThumb,
                "image" = http://mydomain/Imgfull
    } />
```

Pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append things to variables like this:

```
<cfset newThumb = "http://mydomain/"&ImgThumb>
<cfset newImage = "http://mydomain/"&Imgfull>
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: No need to create newThumb and newImage variables - just doing `<cfset obj = { "thumb" = UrlPrefix & ImgThumb , "image" = UrlPrefix & Imgfull } />` works fine. (With `UrlPrefix` being a string set to `http://mydomain/`)

Comment: I had to modify it slightly to work with my existing code, but otherwise it did the trick - thanks!

Comment: Also, to be precise, the terminology is "string concatenation" (rather than "append things to variables").